# What makes NSdata advantageous?

Tags: iphone, nsdata

I've been looking through the apple documentation for the NSdata class, and I didn't really find it too enlightening. I know how to use the class but I don't really understand the gravity of the advantages that it may or may not provide. I know its a simple question but perhaps it would be good to have such information as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advantages over what? Certainly, it's useful to represent an arbitrary block of data as an object just as it's useful to represent a string, a number, or a value as an object. Memory management becomes simpler and is consistent with memory management for all other objects, and there are a number of useful methods defined.

Say you want to read a binary file into memory. We won't worry about the reasons why -- there are as many reasons as there are data file formats. You'll have to:

1. Check the size of the file
2. Allocate a block of memory of the proper size
3. Open the file
4. Read the contents into memory
5. Close the file
6. Remember to free the memory when you're done with it (a condition that can sometimes be tricky to detect)
7. (Optional) Worry about whether the block of memory has been modified

With NSData, you can just create a new instance from a path or URL and not have to think about the rest.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Given that, saving data to a file would be much easier right?

Comment: Sure, it's simple.
`[someData writeToFile:fileName options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&err];`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your advice.